# Display the output of findOne : Object object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using findOne function to find entries inside a table in mySql db. I want to display the output result of the query.

```
async function getChatData(chats,mittente){
    let list;
    for (let i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
        if(chats[i].Userone==mittente){
            await Utente.findOne({ raw: true, where: { id:{[Op.like]:'%'+chats[i].Usertwo+'%'}}})
            .then(function(trovato) {
                console.log(chats[i].Usertwo);
                console.log("------------------------UTENTE TROVATO: "+trovato);                 
                 list.push(trovato);
            })
            .catch(err=>console.log(err))
        }else{
            await Utente.findOne({ raw: true, where: { id:{[Op.like]:'%'+chats[i].Userone+'%'}}})
            .then(function(trovato) {

                 list.push(trovato); 
            })
            .catch(err=>console.log(err))
        }

    };
    console.log(list);
    jsonStr = JSON.stringify(list);
    return jsonStr

}
```

When i try console.log() the output is : Object object.
I would like to see the real result of the query. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean this line:

`console.log("------------------------UTENTE TROVATO: "+trovato);`

You can use

`console.log("------------------------UTENTE TROVATO: "+ JSON.stringify(trovato));`

instead.

Comment: You can just simply pass result as second argument in console.log , also you don't need to convert it into string. Ex : 

    `console.log("------------------------UTENTE TROVATO: ", trovato)`